# How do you pass something like "+ interval 4" to the bindParam

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to pass a variable that looks like this "+ interval 4" or "- interval 5" to this PDO statement.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 
        " . $this->table_name . " (employee_id, work_date) 
        SELECT DISTINCT emp_num, 
        CURDATE() :test DAY FROM " . $this->table_name3 . "";
```

My bindParam

```
$stmt->bindParam(":test", $this->interval);
```

I not sure if I should be using bindValue having a hard time figuring this out.

This works fine but i know it is not right

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO 
        " . $this->table_name . " (employee_id, work_date) 
        SELECT DISTINCT emp_num, 
        CURDATE() " . $this->interval .  " DAY FROM " . $this->table_name3 . "";
```

and here is the whole function if that helps

```
    function sqlbuild(){


    $query = "INSERT INTO 
        " . $this->table_name . " (employee_id, work_date) 
        SELECT DISTINCT emp_num, 
        CURDATE() " . $this->interval .  " DAY FROM " . $this->table_name3 . "";


    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    echo json_encode($stmt);


    $stmt->bindParam(":test", $this->interval); 
    //$stmt->bindParam(1, $this->interval); 

     echo json_encode($this-> interval);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it be that bindValue() autoescapes your value?

Comment: Set `INTERVAL :interval` in the query and then bind to that value. You can't bind the whole thing in there or it will get quoted.

Comment: I agree to @tadman, because `DAY` is already part of your hardcoded query. Having the `INTERVAL` part as a part of the variable makes your query potentially unstable.

Comment: Any suggestions? I could add DAY as part of the variable... I just really need to pass  if its is positive or negative  and the number added INTERVAL to the variable because it was in the middle.